# How do I write a c++ program that will compile itself by being run from the shell?

Tags: c++, bash, shell

I often want to try things out in c++ without going to the trouble of writing a Makefile, creating a project or typing in complex command lines.

I wondered whether it's possible to make a .cpp file which is also a bash script, so it can compile and run itself.

I also wanted to be able to specify command line options in the script, in case there were dependencies like boost and so on.

Comment: Fun fact: you [can use make without writing a Makefile](http://seshbot.com/blog/2014/06/16/make-with-no-makefile-for-c-plus-plus-playgrounds/).

Answer (score 5):

Rather than making a script that is also a cpp file that compiles itself, why not just make a script that watches the cpp file (or dir it is in) and re-compiles the cpp file on any new changes? `inotifywait` was made for that. While this doesn't precisely meet your question requirements, it will keep your code from carrying around all the script baggage. Example:

**.cpp file**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    cout << endl << "Code Running (ver. 10)" << endl << "and being timed." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**inotifywait Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

# watchdir=${1:-$PWD}
src=${1:-app.cpp}   ## set the source and output (exe) names
out=${src%.cpp}

while inotifywait -q -e modify -e modify -e close_write -e delete "$PWD"; do

    printf "\n compiling 'g++ %s -o %s'\n\n" $src $out

    [ -f $out ] && rm $out      ## remove existing exe before building

    g++ -o $out $src            ## build new exe

    [ -f $out ] || {            ## validate new exe created
        printf "error: compilation failed. exiting script.\n\n"
        printf "usage:   %s source.cpp (default: app.cpp)\n\n"
        exit 1
    }

    [ -x $out ] || {            ## validate it is executable
        printf "error: file produced from compilation is not executable.\n"
        exit 1
    }

    time ./$out 2>&1                        ## compute elapsed time
    exesz=$(du -h $out | awk '{print $1}')  ## store disk usage (removing name)

    ## print results
    printf "\n Source file:  %s\n" "$src"
    printf " output file:  %s\n" "$out"
    printf " size of exe:  %s bytes\n\n" "$exesz"

done
```

You can either run the script in the foreground or background. e.g.:

**Example (output on app.cpp save)**

```
$ ./watch.sh
/home/david/scr/tmp/stack/dat/tmp/bld/ MODIFY app.cpp

 compiling 'g++ app.cpp -o app'


Code Running (ver. 10)
and being timed.

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s

 Source file:  app.cpp
 output file:  app
 size of exe:  16K bytes
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of inotifywait. The only problem with this solution for me is that the c++ command not carried with the .cpp file which means that library dependencies and build flags are not co-located with the script. However, using the two techniques together will be really useful.

Comment: You can specify your full compile string within the inotifywait script. You can even make it quite elaborate, if watching a whole directory, by including tests for that provide individual compile options based on the file name.

Answer (score 4):

... it turns out that it is possible:

```
/*/../bin/ls > /dev/null
 filename=$(basename $BASH_SOURCE)
 dirname=$(cd $(dirname $BASH_SOURCE) && pwd)
 if [ "${dirname}" == "$(pwd)" ]
 then
    mkdir -p ${dirname}/bin > /dev/null
    filename="${dirname}/bin/${filename}"
 else
    filename="./${filename}"
 fi
 filename=${filename%.*}
 if [ $0 -nt ${filename} ]
 then
        c++ -o "${filename}" -std=c++1y $BASH_SOURCE || exit
 fi
 ("${filename}" && exit) || echo $? && exit
 exit
*/
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
        cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

In this case I have named the file `skeleton.cpp`:

```
$ chmod +x skeleton.cpp
$ ./skeleton.cpp
Hello, World
```

Comment: Cheap attempt to score some reputation?

Comment: Cheap? This is awesome!

Comment: By all means downvote it if you don't like it. I thought it might be useful to someone.

Comment: @OMGtechy The solution is awesome but asking a question and providing a complex answer within one minute... That is strange. It probably took longer to write the question than find the solution. Hmm.. Maybe the question wasn't a question afterall

Comment: Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Note that this depends on your OS and shell interpreting an executable file that's not a binary and doesn't have a #! tag to start it as a bash script, which may not always be the case.    A variation to this approach would be to make a shell script that does this for you and reference the shell script in a #! tag on the first line  (which your script would have to strip before passing to the compiler).   This way you can easily use this with other files without having to copy the block of stuff each time.

Comment: yes it's more problematic on windows, but there's always cygwin to rescue us from the ghastly cmd shell.

Comment: @StillLearning This is actually encouraged. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101020/clarify-the-self-learner-badge-description

Answer (score 0):

This is the topic of the [Multiline Shebang task on Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiline_shebang).
In September 2011, I wrote the [C solution](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiline_shebang#C):

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -n -e '7,$p' < "$0" | /usr/bin/gcc -x c -o "$0.$$.out" -
$0.$$.out "$0" "$@"
STATUS=$?
rm $0.$$.out
exit $STATUS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    printf("argv[%d] -> %s\n", i, argv[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

This should easily adapt to C++. Basically just change the `-x c` argument to gcc.

At some point I had a version of this which would only compile the executable if it didn't exist or the source was newer; the above always compiles.